# RabbitMQ channel error no exchange found with name 'examplename' in vhost'/'

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, microservices, spring-rabbit

I've been working on a school project with some classmates and we need to use rabbitmq for messaging between microservices. Me and my classmate have the same code (up to date both pulled from a github repo we set up) and he has no error and I keep getting this error  `Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'StudyPlannerAndMonitor_event_bus' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)`
(this is in java/springboot)

However if I look in rabbitmq this eventbus exists and it has a queue, everything looks the  exact same as with my classmate and yet it keeps giving me this bug.
I've already been looking at other people with the same issue and trying those fixes but they dont seem to work, also it seems odd that if it was a code issue that it would not work for me but it does work for other people.

[image]

this is the code that will publish the message on the queue

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("StudyPlannerAndMonitor_event_bus","ScheduleIntegrationEvent",jsonObject.getBytes());
```

I've already looked in to setting cache connection to either "connection" or "channel" both don't change the error or result.

Does anyone have any clue what causes this error knowing it works for another teammate in my project.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Check if you are compiling using the sama java version as your friend.

Comment: yes, I have checked that but i forgot to mention it

Comment: Is your exchange on the same vhost that your are fetching in your app? `in vhost '/',`

Comment: i didnt solve the issue but i just pulled all the code on a different pc and it works on that one so i'll have to do the presentation of the project on that pc. thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with similar problem

To fix it I recreated exchange locally. I use spring so in my case it was like:

```
@Bean
public FanoutExchange fanoutExchange() {
    return new FanoutExchange("exchange-name");
}
```

I ran it once and the error is gone

I removed this code before second launch and everything was alright
I know it is late but maybe it will be helpful for someone